# An XML file can break?

Tags: xml

Well, I want to store information in an XML file and send it to be processed on a server. The structure of the XML file is simple:

```
<name></name>
<age></age>
<sex></sex>
<info></info>
```

The problem is that the information will be saved in the XML, are information that will be inserted by the users through text fields.

Assuming the User inserted a XML tag, and the final file becomes this:

```
<name> <age></name></age> </name>
```

There is a possibility of xml reader encounters a problem and not able to read the file?

Comment: You need to escape all text when writing the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is even very likely. This is why you should always be performing input sanitization:

For examples see here: [santization done in PHP](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/sanitize-database-inputs/)

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is created properly, the value should be encoded:

```
<name> &lt;age&gt;&lt;/name&gt;&lt;/age&gt; </name>
```

That makes the value harmless for the XML, and there is no problem reading it.

Comment: In this case when I read this XML file in server, and put inside a textField I will see <age></name></age>, right?