# Security of writing/retrieving data from JS through PHP

Tags: javascript, php, post, websecurity

I have a web app that lets users make todo-lists, save them to the server and retrieve them by id (no login/user session, only id, so if you guess the id...).

1. The ID is passed from Jquery to PHP via POST.
2. If the ID is correct and not password-protected, PHP echoes the data back to Jquery.
3. New items are saved by POST from Jquery to PHP.

No database. Every list sits in its own file, {ID}.txt. Front-end code used to render the webpage, Ractive.js, escapes all HTML characters.

I'm checking for no extra fields from Jquery to PHP and that the sent ID is in the format I've chosen. The location of the {ID}.txt's is not accessible from the outside.

Is this safe? I'm new to PHP security. I have no idea if there's some very simple thing I just cannot see. I'm guessing this should be fine since the data is stored in txt files and checked for validity.

Do I need to sanitize the inputs in some way? I cannot find a real reason for it. PHP checks for valid IDs using file_exists(). Is that OK?

Thank you a lot. Ask for any other details if needed.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post, the high level concept is still relevant today. Is what you are doing safe? Not really, but that is subjective and to answer critically would require some specific code examples to show how you are capturing the input, formatting it and saving it to file, where and how that file is stored and the later accessed and how the content is rendered.

When talking about *security* in a web application context there are a number of fundamental contexts or *[attack vectors](https://www.upguard.com/blog/attack-vector)* that we might want to consider, not all apply to all scenarios, or even this scenario but the obvious ones that we watch out for in relation to *[sanitizing inputs](https://www.webopedia.com/definitions/input-sanitization/)* in a `POST` against a data store are:

> **NOTE:** This is not supposed to be an exhaustive list, instead it is to demonstrate that the threat is real and more complicated than OP's naive assumption. These are some results from searching the web on this topic:
>
> - [The 10 Most Common Website Security Attacks (and How to Protect Yourself)](https://www.tripwire.com/state-of-security/featured/most-common-website-security-attacks-and-how-to-protect-yourself/)
> - [Top 15 Most Common Security Issues and How to Fix Them](https://www.liquidweb.com/blog/most-common-web-security-problems/)

- **Injection Attacks**
  Injection attacks are not simply restricted to SQL, in fact most modern injection attacks involve input of scripts or commands that will be executed or will affect the *rendering* of the data, not necessarily the storage mechanism. So while your solution does not use a SQL based store, it does nothing to prevent users from injecting javascript commandlets that might be executed when your data is rendered to the screen.

  Even if an attacker is not overly malicious, values could be inserted into the input fields that would conflict with standard file format parsers, perhaps only to  prevent the file from loading. There is a particular brute force process called *Fuzzing* where an attacker deliberately tries to overload input fields to cause an exception, by analysing the type or length of the data and any responses from the server at the point of failure, an attacker might identify vulnerabilities.

> This is an interesting post on a common vulnerability in writing to and reading from XML files: [An XML file can break?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29333265/1690217)

- **Confidentiality**
  Without password-protecting your app, any user could assign tasks to any other user, or could re-assign the users or complete tasks on behalf of other users. In your contrived example, this might not be a concern, but the idea that someone might "guess" a user Id or deliberately obtain or brute force ids, for the purpose of being a pest or a denial of service attack is not something to ignore. If someone decided to write a script to send blank entries for all users starting from `Id=1` right through to `Id=10000000` then users may stop using the site because their ToDo's are gone, or they keep getting bogus data. If the script is active enough, something like that could easily degrade the performance to a level where the site grinds to a halt, even if their plan was not DOS, the end result would be the same.

  Even if you are not using integer keys, brute force attacks like this are just as easy with other data types.
- **Data Integrity / Corruption**
  Attacks against data Integrity or Validity might not directly affect the operation of a *ToDo* app, in other styles of applications it can cause failure when expectations are not met or may provide access to other records that they should not have access to.

  If there are relationships between files, such as grouping or assignment of tasks to other users then if the data input is not validated against known types or values, then a careless or malicious input might prevent data from being displayed, or might allow a user to associate their data with *other* resources that they should not have access to, in this way they may gain access to those other records via association.

---

### What is the actual Risk of attack?

Most attacks against web sites are conducted by *bots* or automated scripts that are simply crawling the web looking for vulnerabilities. Do not think that due to anonymity of your brand or the fact that you do not openly advertise your site that you are protected by *obscurity* and therefore at low risk to a hacker specifically targeting your site.

The reality is that often when we do get hacked, we are not that special at all and haven't done anything specifically to attack their attention other than leaving the door wide open for the attack.

---

### How Authentication Can Help

The obvious benefit that comes from Authentication is that you can scope the data or resources based on the current user. Via *Authorization* or *Filtering* logic you can prevent a user from accessing confidential (or *any*) data generated by other users.

However, having Authentication in place can provide you a simple mechanism to control or prevent some types of attacks. Once you have identified a credential that is being involved in an attack, you can revoke any rights or flat out block that credential from being used, in many cases without affecting access by other authenticated credentials.